# stderr: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not failed to load view for file:///Users/xxx

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode and [vscode-go](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go.git) to develop the `Go` application.

When I try to restart language server using <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shirt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and select "Go: Restart Language Server" option.

Got error:

> Error loading workspace folders (expected 4, got 2) failed to load view for file:///Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/golang: err: exit status 1: stderr: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not failed to load view for file:///Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/graphql-go-cnode: err: exit status 1: stderr: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not

Environment information:

```sh
  gopls version                                                                          
golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.3.4
    golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.3.4 h1:4GC7q/pXQ/tsxHBGVdsMdlB4gCxVC06m/7rIXg1Px4E=
```

```sh
  go env       
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/ldu020/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/ldu020/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/ldu020/workspace/go:/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/golang"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/graphql-go-cnode/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/38/s8g_rsm13yxd26nwyqzdp2shd351xb/T/go-build240831409=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Current work directory:

```sh
  pwd
/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/graphql-go-cnode
```

As you can see, `graphql-go-cnode` is a new project outside of GOPATH, and I use `go mod` command, there is a `go.mod` in the root directory of `graphql-go-cnode` project. For `golang` project, there is a `go.mod` file as well.

```sh
☁  golang [master] ls
LICENSE   README.md bin       go.mod    go.sum    pkg       src
```

Here is my `vscode-go` settings:

```
"go.languageServerFlags": [
    "-rpc.trace",
    "serve",
    "--debug=localhost:6060"
  ],
  "go.toolsGopath": "/Users/ldu020/workspace/go",
  "go.gopath": "/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/golang",
  "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true,
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
```

I follow this [guide](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-use-modules) to create project outside of the GOPATH. But now, I am totally messed up. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out. You need to `uncheck the "Infer GOPATH"` option in the VS code Golang extension. By default, VS code will infer the working directory path as the GOPATH, and that throws an error if your repo implements Go mod.

If your repo implements Go mod, your GOPATH needs to be *outside* of the working directory path, mine is generally set like this:
`export GOPATH="$HOME/go"`

Hope that helps!